# Could not build Objective-C module / No such module

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My iOS app was working perfectly well just a few days ago, and then suddenly I became unable to build it due to seemingly endless problems with Cocoapods.

First I got this error:

[image]

Then I noticed that if I commented out that offending line, I would just get a problem with *another* pod module:
[image]

And another:
[image]

Only `import UIKit` and `import Foundation` don't give that problem.

After I noticed that, I went as far as to delete all the pods and comment out all the code that relied on pods in my project, and attempt to build the app from the bare .xcodeproj file. Then I got this error, as well as a few others:

[image]

I deleted and reinstalled all pods several times, cleaned my DerivedData folder, cleaned to build folder, and visited all pages related to those problems in StackOverflow and other sites. I'm still unable to build the project.

What is going on?

Comment: Did you try `pod deintegrate` and then `pod install` ?

Comment: Yes, several times.

Answer (score 0):

Based on `line 2` in your error message, I assume you had Fabric installed at some point.

Looking at the install steps for it here: https://cocoapods.org/pods/Fabric

It mentions adding an entry in your build phases:
[image]

I would suggest you remove the associated script and try again. Odds are, this fails just before you run the cocoapods scripts.

Comment: Thank you, just did that, unfortunately I am still having the old problems.

Comment: Do you have any other run scripts that may be failing? Would help to list out what you can in an edit to question.

Comment: Right now I have no run scripts.